Materials won't import to unreal engine
I had recently downloaded this Ludex Gunydr model from Deviant Art, as a placeholder for my boss character, so I imported it into Blender, made sure everything was right, deleted a couple of things, and then exported it with the textures, I then tried to import it into unreal, but no matter what I did the textures wouldn't import with the mesh. Do you know how I can fix this?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
